# Bypass login if user already created account

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, swift3, cloudkit

the reason I am asking this question is because I am not using firebase or parse to create accounts. I have used my own code to use CloudKit to login and so on. My question is, after the first time opening the app, and the user making an account, how can I make sure that the following time they open the app, it bypasses the login page? And then, if they logout, the next time they open the app, it takes them to the login page. How can this be done.

TL;DR how can I track whether or not a user has been logged in, and then open the app to a 2 possible scenes based on whether or not they are or are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could keep the user sign in data (like a returned authkey, or a boolean flag) in the Defaults for the app.
Secondly, you could make a "Loading View" where you would check if that data is present.
Lastly, if the data isn't present move him to the login view, else to the main app.